# Cannot defend against undefined in JSX TSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript

// Interface, sometimes Item does not have an id, so the "?" must stay where it is

```
export interface Item {
  id?: number;
  something: string
}
```

props.withItem is of type Item

// Inside the same file, above the return statement this code works and we do not get an error

```
if (props.withItem && props.withItem?.id) removeItem(props.withItem.id) // No error

const removeItem = (itemId: number) => {
  deleteItem(itemId).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```

// Inside jsx we cannot defend against undefined

```
return (
  {props.subItem && props.subItem.id ? (
    <Button
      id='deleteBtn'
      type='danger'
      icon={'delete'}
      label={'Delete'}
      onClick={() => removeItem(props.subItem?.id)} // Error: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
    />
  ) : null}
);
```

What could be causing this?
How can I defend against null in jsx?

Comment: If `subItem` can be null/undefined you might want `props?.subItem?.id`, but it might be better expressed as a negative conditional that early-returns `null` and skip the ternary.

Comment: snippet is inconsistent, in 2nd snippet you are using `props.withItem` but in 3rd you are accessing `props.subItem`.

Comment: @bogdanoff Yeah I would edit it to be correct if I could find the right spot.
They are the same variable though yeah.